# Ubuntu 14.04.2 Laravel 4.2.0 PDOException could not find driver MySQL

Tags: mysql, exception, ubuntu, laravel, pdo

I have no 10 reputation so couldnt add images, sorry.

I want Laravel 4.2.0 working on my Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS Server.

**What I have done until now:**

1. Installing Ubuntu 14.04.2
2. `sudo apt-get install apache2`
3. `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`
4. Install Openssl
5. Install libmcrypt
6. Install PHP by

   ```
      ./configure --with-openssl --with-mcrypt --enable-mbstring --with-pdo-mysql --enable-pdo --with-mysql
   ```

   make
   make install
7. Download Laravel 4.2.0 zip file from GitHub, unzip and transfer it through WinSCP
8. Install Laravel 4.2.0 by

   curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
      php composer.phar install
9. Database connection by configuring /app/config/database.php

   'mysql' => array(
   'driver'    => 'mysql',
   'host'      => 'localhost',
   'database'  => 'laravel',
   'username'  => 'laravel-user',
   'password'  => '************',
   'charset'   => 'utf8',
   'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
   'prefix'    => '',
   ),

And I got this error.

```
PDOException
could not find driver

Open: /var/www/laravel/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php
     */
    public function createConnection($dsn, array $config, array $options)
    {
        $username = array_get($config, 'username');

        $password = array_get($config, 'password');

        return new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
    }
```

I don't know what to do.
I have googled for a day, and got no answer. Please help me.

I checked theres PDO enabled with `php -i|grep PDO` command.

Result:

```
PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => sqlite, mysql
PDO Drivers for MySQL => enabled
PDO Drivers for SQLite 3.x => enabled
```

But I checked php.ini, there's no line like *extension=pdo.so*
So I added the lines like this

```
[Pdo]
; Whether to pool ODBC connections. Can be one of "strict", "relaxed" or "off"
; http://php.net/pdo-odbc.connection-pooling
;pdo_odbc.connection_pooling=strict

;pdo_odbc.db2_instance_name

[Pdo_mysql]
; If mysqlnd is used: Number of cache slots for the internal result set cache
; http://php.net/pdo_mysql.cache_size
pdo_mysql.cache_size = 2000

; Default socket name for local MySQL connects.  If empty, uses the built-in
; MySQL defaults.
; http://php.net/pdo_mysql.default-socket
pdo_mysql.default_socket=

extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension=sqlite.so
```

Please help me out of this frustrating situation..
Thank you in advance for helping me.

Comment: Put this code in your routes.php http://goo.gl/gkZm8V .  Then go to `/phpinfo`  and please check there is `mysql` in PDO support section.

Answer (score 0):

That's means you haven't the extenstion installed.

Install it using:
`sudo apt-get install phpx.x-mysql`
where `x.x` is your php version ex: `php5.6-mysql`
OR just try:
`sudo apt-get install php-mysql`